# How can I set the language_in option for the Closure compiler?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, compiler-options

I need to set the language_in option on the Closure compiler to prevent the IE8 parse error:

ERROR - Parse error. IE8 (and below) will parse trailing commas in array and object literals incorrectly. If you are targeting newer versions of JS, set the appropriate language_in option.

I did find a post in the closure group relating to this, however, the option is set directly on the java compiler, rather than through one of the build scripts. I need to be able to set it on a build script.

I'm looking at the scripts in closure/bin/build/ and there are several there. I tried adding the option to closure builder, but it failed.

Can someone direct me about how to set this option correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: In case you want to add option when compiling through wro4j (Maven) see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872186/ecmascript-5-with-wro4j-and-google-closure-compiler/48442401#48442401

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Run the [Closure Compiler Application](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app) with the `--help` flag to see a description of each flag.

```
java -jar compiler.jar --help
```

[CommandLineRunner](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/f087f70c6e4b595f9a8f8067691de2fa3c8a9e03/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CommandLineRunner.java#L608-L616) defines the set of allowed values for `--language_in`:

> `--language_in`
>   Sets what language spec that input sources conform.
>   Options: ECMASCRIPT3, ECMASCRIPT5, ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT,
>   ECMASCRIPT6_TYPED (experimental), ECMASCRIPT_2015, ECMASCRIPT_2016,
>   ECMASCRIPT_2017, ECMASCRIPT_NEXT

The [LanguageMode enum](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/f087f70c6e4b595f9a8f8067691de2fa3c8a9e03/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilerOptions.java#L3048-L3093) has a bit more detail about these values.

Using [Closure Builder](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/closurebuilder), the `--language_in` flag would be passed as an argument to
`--compiler_flags` as in:

```
--compiler_flags="--language_in=ECMASCRIPT5"
```