# ECMASCRIPT 5 with wro4j and Google Closure Compiler

Tags: maven, google-closure-compiler, ecmascript-5, wro4j

We are using wro4j with Google Closure and Maven to minify our JS. By default it does not suport strict mode in the JS ("use strict";).. it just strips it out. Is there any configuration I can do in `pom.xml` or somewhere else to get it to leave `use strict` in there?

This is the configuration for google closure complier to do it:

```
--language_in=ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT
```

Not sure how to plug that in to Wro4j. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the script you are trying to minimize. Also what is the expected and actual output? This may be rather a problem of Google Closure... and not a wro4j one.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom implementation of the manager factory which adds [ECMAScript5](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ant/CompileTask.java):

```
public class MyCustomWroManagerFactory
extends DefaultStandaloneContextAwareManagerFactory
  {
  @Override 
    protected ProcessorsFactory newProcessorsFactory() 
      {
      final SimpleProcessorsFactory factory = new SimpleProcessorsFactory(); 

      factory.addPreProcessor(
           new GoogleClosureCompressorProcessor(
             CompilerOptions.LanguageMode.ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT
                                               )
                        ); 

      return factory;
      }
  }
```

Reference it in the pom.xml as the value of the [wroManagerFactory](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/MavenPluginCustomization) node:

```
<configuration>
  <wroManagerFactory>com.mycompany.MyCustomWroManagerFactory</wroManagerFactory>
</configuration>
```

> According to John Lenz from the Closure Compiler project, if you are using the Compiler API directly, you should specify a CodingConvention.

**References**

- [GoogleClosureCompressorProcessor.java - method setCompilerOptions](https://github.com/google-code-export/wro4j/blob/master/wro4j-extensions/src/main/java/ro/isdc/wro/extensions/processor/js/GoogleClosureCompressorProcessor.java#L145)
- [GoogleClosureCompressorProcessor.java - optionsPool method](https://github.com/wro4j/wro4j/blob/master/wro4j-extensions/src/main/java/ro/isdc/wro/extensions/processor/js/GoogleClosureCompressorProcessor.java#L89)
- [Closure Compiler Service API Reference - language |  Closure Compiler  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-ref#language)

Comment: GoogleClosureCompressorProcessor does not seem to take a LanguageMode as a param to it's constructor. In fact as far as I can tell GoogleClosureCompressorProcessor no longer has any way to set CompilerOptions.

Comment: You now have to subclass GoogleClosureCompressorProcessor and override newCompilerOptions() to set your custom options.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit more complicated in `wro4j-maven-plugin` 1.8, but not that bad.

You need to add two Java classes. First override `newCompilerOptions` of `GoogleClosureCompressorProcessor` like so:

```java
package com.example.package.wro;

import com.google.javascript.jscomp.CheckLevel;
import com.google.javascript.jscomp.ClosureCodingConvention;
import com.google.javascript.jscomp.CompilerOptions;
import com.google.javascript.jscomp.DiagnosticGroups;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.CharEncoding;
import ro.isdc.wro.extensions.processor.js.GoogleClosureCompressorProcessor;

/**
 * Custom processor overriding `newCompilerOptions` to add custom compiler options.
 *
 * Original author: Alex Objelean.
 */
public class CustomGoogleClosureCompressorProcessor extends GoogleClosureCompressorProcessor {

    /**
     * Encoding to use.
     */
    public static final String ENCODING = CharEncoding.UTF_8;

    @Override
    protected CompilerOptions newCompilerOptions() {
        final CompilerOptions options = new CompilerOptions();

        // Set the language_in option on the Google Closure Compiler to prevent errors like:
        // "JSC_TRAILING_COMMA. Parse error. IE8 (and below)"
        options.setLanguageIn(CompilerOptions.LanguageMode.ECMASCRIPT5);

        /**
         * According to John Lenz from the Closure Compiler project, if you are using the Compiler API directly, you should
         * specify a CodingConvention. {@link http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/issues/detail?id=155}
         */
        options.setCodingConvention(new ClosureCodingConvention());
        // use the wro4j encoding by default
        //options.setOutputCharset(Charset.forName(getEncoding()));
        setEncoding(ENCODING);
        options.setOutputCharset(Charset.forName(ENCODING));
        // set it to warning, otherwise compiler will fail
        options.setWarningLevel(DiagnosticGroups.CHECK_VARIABLES, CheckLevel.WARNING);
        return options;
    }
}
```

You'll notice I've commented out the line `getEncoding`. This is because it's private. I also added `setEncoding` just in case.

Then we need the Custom manger:

```java
package com.example.package.wro;

import ro.isdc.wro.manager.factory.standalone.DefaultStandaloneContextAwareManagerFactory;
import ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.factory.ProcessorsFactory;
import ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.factory.SimpleProcessorsFactory;

/**
 * Custom manger adding custom processor.
 */
public class CustomWroManagerFactory extends DefaultStandaloneContextAwareManagerFactory {

    @Override
    protected ProcessorsFactory newProcessorsFactory() {
        final SimpleProcessorsFactory factory = new SimpleProcessorsFactory();

        factory.addPreProcessor(
            new CustomGoogleClosureCompressorProcessor()
        );

        return factory;
    }
}
```

And then use it in your `pom.xml` in `wroManagerFactory`. Something like so:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <!-- Google Closure Compiler -->
            <!-- http://www.gzfs020.com/using-google-closure-compiler-with-wro4j-maven-plugin.html -->
            <configuration>
                <contextFolder>${basedir}/src/main</contextFolder>
                <wroFile>${basedir}/src/main/config/wro.xml</wroFile>
                <destinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/min</destinationFolder>
                <!--
                <wroManagerFactory>ro.isdc.wro.extensions.manager.standalone.GoogleStandaloneManagerFactory</wroManagerFactory>
                -->
                <wroManagerFactory>com.example.package.wro.CustomWroManagerFactory</wroManagerFactory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```